# How can I prevent an element from being styled by light DOM styling?

Tags: html, css, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to wrap my head around the light DOM and shadow DOM concepts.

What I am figuring out to do here is how to move the light dom part, inside the shadow dom so it does not get styled by the .foo selector...

I got this

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" constructor="" attributes="" noscript>
  <template>
    - <content></content> -
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

And my element is used like so:

```
<my-element>
    <div class="foo">Shadow</div>
</my-element>
```

Now what I understand is that the div inside my-element gets tossed into the light dom (And gets styled by .foo), and `<my-element></my-element>` is what gets put inside the shadow DOM.

But, how can I put the div inside the shadow dom as well? (in effect hiding it from .foo)

example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mLT5G/52/

**edit: A more real world example would be something along the lines of**

```
<cards>
   <card>
     <h3>Title</h3>
     <p>Body</p>
   <card>
<cards>
```

From what I understand now, in essence I would be making 2 custom components here.

So, one for **cards**, which imports **card** 
However the H3 and P will always take on the default styling of the page it's been put into? (If not overridden...)

Would I need to make another custom component? So instead of the H3 I create `card-title` and the p would be inserted by `<content></content>`

I realise I can do it like that, but I am wondering if that is the way to go.

Comment: Don't add the class `.foo`? Really, the point of Light DOM is that it's supposed to be under the control of the element user (while still allowing access to it from within the component). If styles suddenly aren't applying to certain elements and you can't find out why without digging into custom element source code, that breaks the desired encapsulation and separation of concerns that Web Components bring.

Comment: If you want the Light DOM element to be purely an API parameter and not be styleable at all, use an `<option>` or `<source>` tag instead of a `<div>`, like `<select>` and `<video>` do, respectively.

Comment: Then I was probably thinking about it the wrong way. Could you check my edit to see if I am on the right track? Thanks!!

Comment: Great edit! I don't have a straight answer for you, but it looks like you're on the right path. Two things: Only create custom components for `<cards>` and `<card>` if there is JS behavior that needs to be attached to them. If you just need `<cards>` to know which of its children to consume, for example, just put a `card` attribute on a couple child `div`s (like [`core-drawer-panel`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-drawer-panel)). Then you can just use `<content>`'s `select` attribute with a CSS attribute selector (eg, `<content select="[card]">`).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25565699/1431146) might be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful!

I also found out the hard way that Polymer has its limitations with regards to style definition from the host page bleeding into the shadow DOM. So, no real CSS encapsulation as of yet.

Comment: There shouldn't be any bleeding on native Shadow DOM (other than normal font-style inheritance, etc.). What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Chrome, which skips Polymer all together and uses the Native  WC implementation (Because it has support for it), which does not bleed. However when using Firefox, author styles bleed into the shadow dom...Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdyqo9ms/

Comment: You're absolutely right. Polymer doesn't attempt to polyfill Shadow DOM completely, which would be insanely complex.

Comment: For the original title of how to move elements, [this article](https://matthewminer.name/blog/how-to-scope-css-by-moving-an-element-to-the-shadow-dom) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `::content` selector to try to override any styles that the page may have applied: http://jsbin.com/muyapu/2/edit

Or you could use the [new `all` property to reset styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all), however it's only supported in Chrome and Firefox. http://jsbin.com/daxaf/2/edit