# Decorate elements from <content>

Tags: polymer

I have a `form-el` who is just a container who must wrap all childrens inside a `div` with specific classes. Instead of repeating this `div` in each form elements I would like to allow the `from-el` to wrap them. 
Can I loop over all  elements and wrap them inside other html tags ?

```
// Markup
<form-el>
    <input-el label="name" type="text" />
    <span>This must also be wrapped</span>
</form-el>

// Would produce
<form>
    <div class="form-field">
       <label>name</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
       <span>This must also be wrapped</span>
    </div>
</form>
// Where '<div class="form-field">' is produced by 'from-el'
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to achieve this is by template-repeating `<content>` nodes tailored to your light-dom, like so:

```
<polymer-element name="form-el">
<template>

  <template repeat="{{wrappers}}">
    <div style="border: 2px solid orange; padding: 2px; margin: 4px">
      <content select="[key='{{}}']">
    </div>
  </template>

</template>
<script>

  Polymer({
    domReady: function() {
      this.updateWrappers();
    },
    updateWrappers: function() {
      this.wrappers = [];
      for (var i=0, n=this.firstChild; n; n=n.nextSibling) {
        if (n.setAttribute) {
          // attach a selectable key to each light-dom node
          n.setAttribute('key', i);
          // specify a <content> with that key
          this.wrappers.push(i++);
        }
      }
    }
  });

</script>
</polymer-element>
```

http://jsbin.com/mukip/5/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I try to wrap polymer elements it only display  the first one. http://jsbin.com/sadexakoyuco/1/edit

Comment: No custom elements can be void, iow, you can't use `<input-el/>` you must use `<input-el></input-el>`.

Comment: @ScottMiles how/when can I get the wrapper? as templates are stamped and distributed asynchronously, I cannot get the reference to `this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("div")` immediately after `this.updateWrappers();` is simple `setTimeout` enough?
In simplified case it works http://jsbin.com/zuxiqo/1/edit , but will it be enough to avoid any race condition?