# Wrapping Polymer child elements in other element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to make a component that will wrap it's children with some other series of components or elements, here is simplified example of my actual code, let's say I've developed a container element, and I want to add a series of images to it's `content` (or `shadow` doesn't really matter to me I think) element such as this:

```
<!-- my-app.html -->
<my-container>
 <img src="a.png">
 <img src="b.png">
 <img src="c.png">
</my-container>
```

Now, behind the scenes I would like to wrap each image, for example with another set of elements, so I define my `my-container` polymer component as follows:

```
<polymer-element name="my-container">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bo-examplr.css">
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    <template bind="{{children as children}}" repeat="{{child in children}}">
      <div>
        <h5>Some Property will go here eventually</h5>
        <content></content>
    </template>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

That's as far as I got, and of course it doesn't work, did anyone else tried to accomplish it and was more successful than I am?

[Gist of actual source code](https://gist.github.com/nirth/e5830f6717fd43d72a8a)

Comment: Populating like in [this example](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html#templates-with-data-binding)  is not an option?

Comment: That's my plan C (Plan B, is reading inner children, deleting them and repopulating them wrapped in templates manually). But want to see if I'm missing something and do it "properly" without additional logic.

Comment: What about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564150/decorate-elements-from-content/25565699#25565699)?

Comment: @CletusW Thanks a lot, I've implemented it and I guess my question is a duplicate and should be removed!

Comment: I guess so. I actually like how you worded the question better, but oh well :)